# PCL: no suitable conversion function when i use std::bind in setConditionFunction

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I'm sorry to ask this question, but I'm really pretty new in C++.

I want to use `pcl::ConditionalEuclideanClustering::setConditionFunction` in my class function. and use another class function as the parameter.

I have referenced the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29564245/function-pointer-error-in-c/36697410#36697410) and other codes. But still have the question when I use `cec.setConditionFunction (std::bind(&tube_detect::customRegionGrowing, this, _1, _2, _3));`:

> no suitable conversion function from "std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<bool (tube_detect::*)(const PointTypeFull &point_a, const PointTypeFull &point_b, float squared_distance)> (tube_detect *, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>)>" to "bool (*)(const PointTypeFull &, const PointTypeFull &, float)" exists

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>

#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/console/time.h>

#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>
#include <pcl/features/normal_3d.h>
#include <pcl/segmentation/conditional_euclidean_clustering.h>

typedef pcl::PointXYZI PointTypeIO;
typedef pcl::PointXYZINormal PointTypeFull;

class tube_detect{
  public:
    pcl::PointCloud<PointTypeIO>::Ptr cloud_in, cloud_out;
    pcl::PointCloud<PointTypeFull>::Ptr cloud_with_normals ;
    pcl::IndicesClustersPtr clusters , small_clusters, large_clusters;
    pcl::search::KdTree<PointTypeIO>::Ptr search_tree;
    pcl::console::TicToc tt;
    // tube_detect();
    void copy_load_point_cloud(pcl::PointCloud<PointTypeFull>::Ptr copy_cloud_with_normal);
    void modify_intensity_indices();
    void normal();
    bool customRegionGrowing(const PointTypeFull& point_a, const PointTypeFull& point_b, float squared_distance);

};

void tube_detect::normal(){
    // Set up a Conditional Euclidean Clustering class
     std::cerr << "Segmenting to clusters...\n", tt.tic ();
     pcl::ConditionalEuclideanClustering<PointTypeFull> cec (true);
     cec.setInputCloud (cloud_with_normals);
      
     // **here is the error happen**
     cec.setConditionFunction (std::bind(&tube_detect::customRegionGrowing, this, _1, _2, _3));
     

     cec.setClusterTolerance (1.0);
     cec.setMinClusterSize (cloud_with_normals->points.size () / 1000);
     cec.setMaxClusterSize (cloud_with_normals->points.size () / 5);
     cec.segment (*clusters);
     cec.getRemovedClusters (small_clusters, large_clusters);
     std::cerr << ">> Done: " << tt.toc () << " ms\n";
}

bool 
tube_detect::customRegionGrowing (const PointTypeFull& point_a, const PointTypeFull& point_b, float squared_distance)
{
  Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Vector3f> point_a_normal = point_a.getNormalVector3fMap (), point_b_normal = point_b.getNormalVector3fMap ();
  if (squared_distance < 1)
  {
    if (std::abs (point_a.intensity - point_b.intensity) < 8.0f)
      return (true);
    if (std::abs (point_a_normal.dot (point_b_normal)) < 0.1)
      return (true);
  }
  else
  {
    if (std::abs (point_a.intensity - point_b.intensity) < 3.0f)
      return (true);
  }
  return (false);
}
```

=============================

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ***PCL-1.7*** and it is installed when I install ***ROS-Kinetic***.

`setConditionFunction` is only defined as:

```
      inline void
      setConditionFunction (bool (*condition_function) (const PointT&, const PointT&, float)) 
      {
        condition_function_ = condition_function;
      }
```

So, I can't use `std::bind`.

btw, [it](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues/284#issuecomment-644246805) seems like that I can not use higher pcl version.

> For each ROS distribution, per REP 103, we only officially support 1 PCL version.

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with a similar problem. I wanted to filter by a variable parameter `external_parameter`, but could not pass it by the parameter list, because the [`pcl::ConditionalEuclideanClustering::setConditionFunction`](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_conditional_euclidean_clustering.html#a62bf691a0260fc34c3df9d9d48cb2faa) only takes objects of the defined parameter list (const auto& point_a, const auto& point_b, float squared_distance).

The solution was to pass a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) function, that captures the external parameter by reference...

```
auto lambda = [&external_parameter](const auto& point_a, const auto& point_b, float squared_distance){
if(std::abs (point_a.some_value - point_b.some_value) < external_parameter)
   return true;
else
   return false;
};
```

... and to pass the reference to `cec`.

```
cec.setConditionFunction(lambda);
```

I hope this helps you further.